# jQuery Image Zoom With Mouse Wheel or Touch Scroll

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

hello i have simple div with 500x500 in html page including jQuery. i want to use image in div, on image click it will zoom within div. image size 1320x917. 
and also i can scroll image with mouse.

**HTML code** :

```
<div class="div1">
   <img src="imag1.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS code** :

```
.div1{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this this is best zoom for you 
>   [Photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**try this css:**

```
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

**demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/bqtd7xef/1/

Comment: dear chirag this is not working i want to use within div (w 500px - h 500px).
and image not display out site of div. and also i can't scroll image with mouse.

Comment: no dear this is not work i can't scroll image with mouse not only zoom but i can also scroll image with mouse.
check this : https://jsfiddle.net/bhavhirani/bqtd7xef/5/.         and image not display out site div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery plugin for image zooming functionality.
Please have a look at [this](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)